# CsvHelper dynamic column mapping

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am following this example to map custom column names to my class model:

[CsvHelper Mapping by Name](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-name/)

In this particular part:

```
public FooMap()
{
    Map(m => m.Id).Name("ColumnA");
    Map(m => m.Name).Name("ColumnB");
}
```

Is it possible to use string as column name instead of hard-code it? Something like this --

```
public FooMap()
{
    Map("Col1").Name("ColumnA");
    Map("Col2").Name("ColumnB");
}
```

"Col1" and "Col2" are the property of my class model. I've tried to use reflection but it didn't work:

```
Map(x => typeof(MyClassModel).GetProperty("Col1")).Name("ColumnA");
```

Please let me know if what I am trying to achieve is possible. Some additional info -- the column mapping (source and destination) are both stored in a table.

Thanks!

Comment: From experience I don't think it's possible without using a code generator to create the  `ClassMap` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay. Right now, I am just manually mapping each column in my class model to a custom name. There are lots of fields! That's why I wonder if I can use dynamic names and just use a single loop that would map all columns. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should allow you to use a string to map both the property name and the header name.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Id","FooId"},
        {"Name","FooName"}
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("FooId,FooName\n1,Jordan"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var fooMap = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();

        fooMap.Map(mapping);
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(fooMap);
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }   
}

public static class CsvHelperExtensions
{
    public static void Map<T>(this ClassMap<T> classMap, IDictionary<string, string> csvMappings)
    {
        foreach (var mapping in csvMappings)
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(mapping.Key);

            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Class {typeof(T).Name} does not have a property named {mapping.Key}");
            }

            classMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Name(mapping.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: You still have to explicitly define the Foo class?  I configure mapping in appsettings.  CSV files are read into a List<dynamic>

Comment: @JeremyA.West Yes this was to be able to dynamically map to a specific class.  You can certainly read in a `List<dynamic>` and do a lot with that. If you then want it mapped to a specific class, then you are going to need some method to map between the dynamic object and your class.

Comment: I was attempting to read in a CSV file, rename the headers, then send the CSV on to Salesforce Bulk API (which requires specific headers).  To make the application reusable in the future I want to keep all the mappings in appsettings.  I have this working using a separate function, but felt the Map would be a cleaner approach.  This line `var fooMap = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();` would be something like `var fooMap = new DefaultClassMap<dynamic>();` but I don't think that works.

Comment: No sorry, `ClassMap` is looking for a class.  Dynamic is not going to work with mapping. If you look at the `WriteDynamicHeader` method, mapping is not used like it is in the `WriteHeader` method.  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/9848510ed0fc0980bda687882c5ea123b7d7d3ce/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L307 https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/9848510ed0fc0980bda687882c5ea123b7d7d3ce/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L252

Answer (score 1):

As an another approach, define an XML/JSON config file where you can define the columns you want to map. Write a parser that could parse your XML/JSON config and return the columns to be mapped dynamically. This approach allows you to map any no of columns on fly, without having to recompile your code.

Comment: My column mapping is already in a table. My problem is not knowing how to make both the source and destination column dynamic as variables. Do you have a code sample for your XML/JSON mapping? Thanks!